# Azure Build Pipeline cannot locate a file in dotnet core project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a PowerShell script in a folder in the source code for my project. I am trying to execute the file to make a third party call at the end of my build pipeline. When I look at the source repo the file is in the following folder:

ProjectName\Scripts\pwsh\PowerShell1.ps1

The build pipeline has the following task:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Third Party Call
  inputs: 
    filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ProjectName\Scripts\pwsh\PowerShell1.ps1'
  pwsh: true
```

I get the following error:

```
##[error]Invalid file path 'D:\a\1\s\ProjectName\scripts\pwsh\PowerShell1.ps1'. A path to a .ps1 file is required.
```

It is my understanding that $(Build.SourcesDirectory) is the root directory of the source of the project, so I assumed it would have the same folder structure as my repo. I don't know where to go from here as I can't see what is in $(Build.SourcesDirectory) to alter the file path to the correct location of my PowerShell script. Can someone advise me where I need to point please?

Edit: full yml file for the pipeline.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use dotnet 7'
  inputs:
    version: '7.0.x'
    packageType: runtime

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: 'DatabaseBuild'
    maximumCpuCount: true
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      **/*.dacpac
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: New Relic Deployment Marker
  inputs: 
    filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ProjectName\scripts\pwsh\PowerShell1.ps1'
    arguments: '-ApiKey "$(ApiKey)" -EntityGuid "$(EntityId)" -Version "1.0.0" -Description "Deployed by Azure CI/CD" -User "DevOps"'
    pwsh: true
```

[image: Project Folder Structure]

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see if in a previous step you see the artifact downloaded or repository checked out to that location? Sources is usually something like D:\a\1\s which is where the repository is checked out to. Is the ps1 part of that repository or of a different source or artifact used in the build pipeline?

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg the previous step is a PublishBuildArtifacts@1. Could that be removing the build directory?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, might be easier if your post the full yaml (censored if you want)

Comment: @DaveyvanTilburg I've put in the full yml file. It's a simple pipeline. Does a publish of the project and writes it to the Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory, builds a dacpac from the database project and puts it in the artifacts directory and finally attempts to call the PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a build agent does not create ProjectName folder. It just checkouts to the root of `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. You may try:

```
filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ProjectName\Scripts\pwsh\PowerShell1.ps1'
```

or just a relative path from the current folder:

```
filePath: './Scripts/pwsh/PowerShell1.ps1'
```

Comment: The root folder where the solution file exists has four folders containing separate projects. The four folders are ProjectName, ProjectName.Core, ProjectName.Database and ProjectName.Infrastructure. Hence, why I included the folder in my path.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make this an answer as the story is a bit long :)

You do not have a specific checkout task or download artifact task in your YAML, meaning the repository is checked out directly (not with a project/artifact or repository name) into the sources directory. So what do you mean by 'ProjectName'?, is that a folder in the root of the repository? Or is 'scripts' in the root of the repository?

You have to make the path after $(Build.SourcesDirectory) relative from the root in the repository used by the pipeline.

Other artifacts used will be added to the sourcesdirectory with their relative name,

for example:

```
- download: current
  artifact: some-drop
```

will be located in $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\some-drop\

But this is not the case for you

Comment: The root folder where the solution file exists has four folders containing separate projects. The four folders are ProjectName, ProjectName.Core, ProjectName.Database and ProjectName.Infrastructure. Hence, why I included the folder in my path and the scripts folder is in the ProjectName folder.

Comment: I've added an image of the project structure to the post that shows that the scripts are in the ProjectName folder.

Comment: Turns out I'm an idiot. I was working on a branch to get my pipeline correct that didn't contain the scripts folder. Once it was included it all worked as expected. This question will shortly be deleted.